# React Native Calculator

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have made an React Native Calculator which is working like normal calculators. However I have to make certain changes like

```
100+100 = 220 not 200

100-100 = 10 not 0

100*100 = 140 not 10,000

100/100 = 0 not 1
```

I tried but its not working.
Can anybody suggest the changes in the code.

Here is my app.js code :

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";

import InputNumberButton from "./InputNumberButton";

const buttons = [
  ["C", "±", "%", "÷"],
  ["7", "8", "9", "x"],
  ["4", "5", "6", "-"],
  ["1", "2", "3", "+"],
  ["0", ".", "DEL", "="]
];

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.initialState = {
      displayValue: "0",
      operator: null,
      firstValue: "",
      secondValue: "",
      nextValue: false
    };
    this.state = this.initialState;
  }

  renderButtons() {
    let layouts = buttons.map((buttonRows, index) => {
      let rowItem = buttonRows.map((buttonItems, buttonIndex) => {
        return (
          <InputNumberButton
            value={buttonItems}
            handleOnPress={this.handleInput.bind(this, buttonItems)}
            key={"btn-" + buttonIndex}
          />
        );
      });

      return (
        <View style={styles.inputRow} key={"row-" + index}>
          {rowItem}
        </View>
      );
    });

    return layouts;
  }

  handleInput = input => {
    const {
      displayValue,
      operator,
      firstValue,
      secondValue,
      nextValue
    } = this.state;

    switch (input) {
      case "0":
      case "1":
      case "2":
      case "3":
      case "4":
      case "5":
      case "6":
      case "7":
      case "8":
      case "9":
      case "0":
      case "0":
        this.setState({
          displayValue: displayValue === "0" ? input : displayValue + input
        });
        if (!nextValue) {
          this.setState({
            firstValue: firstValue + input
          });
        }
        else {
          this.setState({
            secondValue: secondValue + input
          });
        }

        break;
      case "+":
      case "-":
      case "x":
      case "÷":
      case "%": 
        this.setState({
          nextValue: true,
          operator: input,
          displayValue:
            (operator !== null 
              ? displayValue.substr(0, displayValue.length - 1)
              : displayValue ) + input,
        });
        break;
      case "±":  
      this.setState({
        // son değer nokta değilse displayValue yeni girdiğimiz değeri de yanına alıyor
        // we checked last char, if it is not a dot, we add new input to displayValue
        displayValue: operator !== "±" ? -Math.abs(displayValue) : -Math.abs(displayValue)
      });
        break; 
      case ".":
        let nokta = displayValue.toString().slice(-1); // son karakteri aldık - we took last char
        this.setState({
          // son değer nokta değilse displayValue yeni girdiğimiz değeri de yanına alıyor
          // we checked last char, if it is not a dot, we add new input to displayValue
          displayValue: nokta !== "." ? displayValue + input : displayValue
        });
        if (!nextValue) {
          this.setState({
            firstValue: firstValue + input
          });
        } else {
          this.setState({
            secondValue: secondValue + input
          });
        }
        break;

      case "=":
        let formatOperator =
          operator == "x" ? "*" : operator == "÷" ? "/" : operator;

        let result = eval(firstValue + formatOperator + secondValue);
        this.setState({
          displayValue: result % 1 === 0 ? result : result.toFixed(2),
          firstValue: result % 1 === 0 ? result : result.toFixed(2),
          secondValue: "",
          operator: null,
          nextValue: false
        });
        break;
      case "C":
        this.setState(this.initialState);
        break;
      case "DEL":
        let string = displayValue.toString();
        let newString = string.substr(0, string.length - 1);
        let length = string.length;
        this.setState({
          displayValue: length == 1 ? "0" : newString,
          firstValue: length == 1 ? "" : newString
        });
        break;
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.resultContainer}>

          <Text style={styles.resultText}>{this.state.displayValue}</Text>

        </View>
        <View style={styles.inputContainer}>{this.renderButtons()}</View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1
  },
  resultContainer: {
    flex: 2,
    backgroundColor: "#000",
    justifyContent: "center"
  },
  inputContainer: {
    flex: 8,
    backgroundColor: "#000"
  },
  resultText: {
    color: "white",
    fontSize: 80,
    fontWeight: "bold",
    padding: 20,
    textAlign: "right"
  },
  inputRow: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: "row"
  }
});
```

and here is the button styles InputNumberButton from "./InputNumberButton"

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";

export default class InputNumberButton extends Component {
  render() {
    const { value, handleOnPress } = this.props;

    return (
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={styles.container}
        onPress={() => handleOnPress(value)}
      >
        <Text style={styles.text}>{value}</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    margin: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#d98f42",
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center"
  },
  text: {
    color: "#000",
    fontSize: 26
  }
});
```

Kindly suggest. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Im still having a hard time following your code. More commenting would nice. I've spent the last few minutes trying to understand this

```js
 this.setState({
          nextValue: true,
          operator: input,
          displayValue:
            (operator !== null 
              ? displayValue.substr(0, displayValue.length - 1)
              : displayValue ) + input,
        });
        break;
```

A comment saying something about operator replacement would've saved me some time